# How do I test for blanks in array (dtype object)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a df that has some blanks in it. Whenever there is a blank I want to be able to substitute it with "0000". However, I can't find a way to replace the blanks in my array. Some of the values in the array are numbers, but sometimes the element has multiple numbers delimited by ";". Can anyone help?

[image: Image of df, including blank cell (row 3 Numbers)]

Comment: `0000` **is not the same** as `"0000"` In any case, your loop *never modifies your `pd.Series`*. Why did you *expect* it to change?

Comment: I'm just looking for a way to identify when it is blank. Simply illustrative

Comment: You shouldn't be using a for-loop to begin with here. You want something like `df.loc[df["Numbers"].isnull(), 'Numbers'] = 0`

Comment: *What do you mean by **blank**? Blank is not a standard terminology. I think you mean `NaN`, in which case, just use what I showed above. Although note, `0000` *is the same* as `0`, it seems like you may actually want the *string* `"0000"` but the same approach would work either way

Comment: Thanks for the 0000 catch -- how can I modify my df to 1) recognize blanks and 2) change them to a new value?

Comment: Thank you!! Works perfect. I just needed the "isnull()" terminology!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)
Include it as a [formatted code block](//stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) instead of an image. 
[Why do we hate screenshots so much?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/)

Comment: @Kyle, see answer below. If that works for you -- based on the comments it does -- please accept so the community knows to move on. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

If by 'blank' you mean 'NaN' and by '0000' you mean a string of '0000' and not the integer '0', the following should work:

```
df.loc[df['Numbers'].isnull(), 'Numbers'] = '0000'
```

What's going on here is the following:

1. `.isnull()` is a built-in pandas function that will detect if an entry is a `NaN`.
2. `[df['Numbers'].isnull()` will return only the locations in the dataframe for which there is a `NaN` in the 'Numbers' column.
3. `df.loc[index, column]` will select all the rows (index) that meet the condition -- in this case isnull() == True -- and then replace the values in the column in those rows with whatever is specified, in this case the string '0000'.

Welcome to Pandas!